# DoubleTap in hammer.js 2.0 not recognized after panning the element

Tags: hammer.js

DoubleTap not recognized in hammer.js after panning the element.

```js
var singleTap = new Hammer.Tap({event:'singletap',taps:1});
var doubleTap = new Hammer.Tap({event:'doubletap',taps:2,posThreshold:3000,threshold:300});
var tripleTap = new Hammer.Tap({event:'tripletap',taps: 3 });

mcViewer.add([tripleTap, doubleTap, singleTap]);

tripleTap.recognizeWith([doubleTap, singleTap]);
doubleTap.recognizeWith(singleTap);
doubleTap.requireFailure(tripleTap);
singleTap.requireFailure([tripleTap, doubleTap]);
```

Comment: Please provide more information (e.g. what's the code that instantiates `mcViewer`? What manages the pan?) and please format code.